# Можно ли как-то на локальном компьютере иметь несколько версий PHP и работать с каждой по отдельности?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Коллеги, хотел бы у вас спросить, есть ли такое решение, которое позволит переключать локально версии PHP (не интересуют готовые серверы типо MAMP/OpenServer)

Answer (score 1):

вариант влоб: установить себе несколько версий языка, и пользоваться алиасами, типа

```
alias php80="sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0"
alias php71="sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1"
alias php72="sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2"
alias php73="sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3"
alias php74="sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4"
```

вариант более хитрый: docker.